# How to see via pprof web what exactly in my funcs produced allocs?

Tags: go, memory-management, benchmarking

Steps:

1. go test -bench . -benchmem -memprofile memprofile.out -cpuprofile cpuprofile.out
2. go tool pprof -web memprofile.out
3. [image: get cumulative nonsense view]

All i was able to do.

Comment: Could you clarify the problem please?

Comment: @cooleck i found what's the problem, see the answer below. and thanks for your readiness to help!

Answer (score 1):

the problem was `pprof -web` does not include to memory profile graph
such things as runtime operations (both `Group` and `FastGroup` contain only map/slice-related stuff, no func calls).

the only workaround here is to add `-lines` option to see on graph not only `Func`, but `Func:N` where `N` is the line where exactly allocs were in `Func`